# What’s the limit of a vector bundle?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, geometric-measure-theory

In geometric measure theory, there’s an answer to the question “what’s the limit of a family of submanifolds”, namely there’s some kind of object called an integral current.

In the geometric questions arising from modern physics, one is often interested in submanifolds equipped with other structures; vector bundles, vector bundles with connection, etc.

Does geometric measure theory provide tools for understanding limits of such objects?

What’s the limit of a family of submanifolds carrying vector bundles?

Carrying vector bundles with connection?

Comment: In algebraic geometry one can consider the/a "limit" of a flat familty of semistable vector bundles on the same projective variety: it's no longer a vector bundle but a coherent sheaf belonging to the "boundary" of the moduli space of semistable sheaves. Probably one can consider also families in which also the base variety varies (is *deformed*) along with a vector bundle on it, and take such flat limits.

Comment: Indeed, when one can force such a question into the world of algebraic geometry, the compactness theorems on moduli are powerful tools.  However many questions of interest are not algebro-geometric.  For these I would nevertheless like compactness theorems, and characterizations of limits of reasonable objects.  Geometric measure theory is (apparently) concerned with providing such results, hence the question.

Comment: You could consider varifolds (in the sense of Allard).  These are Radon measures on the Grassman bundle of $k$-planes over some base space (for simplicity, say $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>k$).  Given a $k$-dimensional submanifold one cooks up the corresponding varifold by taking the measure that projects to Hausdorff measure of the submanifold on the base $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the dirac mass of the tangent plane on each fiber.  One can use standard compactness for measures to get limits with smeared out tangents.  Your question is vague, but this seems like what you want, for the tangent bundle at least.